# AlarmManager doesn't come up at time

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, alarmmanager

I'm trying to build the alarm and the time to wakeup  is set in the SQLite DB

I had already get the time to millisecond from DB

But it doesn't bring out the alarm at the time

I think this might be a poor method, if there is any  better way please tell me

Below is my DB class

```
 public Cursor filList(long id) throws SQLException{
    Cursor cursor = db.query(
            "ALARM",
            new String[] {"_id","Atime"},
            "_id ="  +id,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null
    );
    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();   
    }
    return cursor;
}
public int update(long rowId, String value) {
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    args.put("Atime", value);

    return db.update("ALARM",   //資料表名稱
            args,               //VALUE
            "_id=" + rowId,         //WHERE
            null                //WHERE的參數
    );
}

public boolean isEmpty(){
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS"+  " ALARM " +"(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , " + "Aname VAR UNIQUE   , " +"Atime TIME)");
    Cursor cursor = db.query(
            "ALARM",
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null
    );
    if (cursor.getCount() ==0) {
        return  false;  //將指標移到第一筆資料
    }
    else
        return  true;
}
```

Below is get data from DB

```
   if(helper.isEmpty()){
      Cursor morn = helper.filList(1);
      Cursor noo = helper.filList(2);
      Cursor ni = helper.filList(3);
      Cursor mid = helper.filList(4);
      alarm(morn.getString(1));
      alarm(noo.getString(1));
      alarm(ni.getString(1));
      alarm(mid.getString(1));
    }
```

Below is alarm

```
public void alarm (String alarmtimein) {


    SimpleDateFormat time = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MM dd HH:mm");
    SimpleDateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MM dd");
    try {
        Intent intent11 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PlayReceiver.class);
         Date today  = new Date();
         String s = date.format(today);
        String times = s + " " + alarmtimein;
        Date alarmtimeout = time.parse(times);
        long milliseconds = alarmtimeout.getTime();
        intent11.putExtra("msg", "play_voice");
        long elapsed =  milliseconds;
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 1, intent11,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,elapsed , pi);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing set method with setExact.

```
public void alarm (String alarmtimein) {


SimpleDateFormat time = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MM dd HH:mm");
SimpleDateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MM dd");
try {
    Intent intent11 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), 
    PlayReceiver.class);
     Date today  = new Date();
     String s = date.format(today);
    String times = s + " " + alarmtimein;
    Date alarmtimeout = time.parse(times);
    long milliseconds = alarmtimeout.getTime();
    intent11.putExtra("msg", "play_voice");
    long elapsed =  milliseconds;
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 
    1, intent11,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
am.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,elapsed , pi);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}}
```